# Cannot decode Coinbase secret

Tags: api, signing, coinbase-api

I created a key for Coinbase according to their instructions.
https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/api-key-authentication

However the secret they provide cannot be decoded. At first I thought it could be my code, but when I used the following website, they cannot decode the secret either. Is there another was to decode Base64?

https://devpal.co/base64-decode/

[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s3gI.png)

Here is the secret that Coinbase provided in their sandbox environment. The key has since been deleted.
9LSLaXxMTY/ucSj9AvsCEobGqsJAnvPQbEBDSHmX+XyjGcbSvFzc2mXQCZjudLv36oxuZSM3U15yydyIWdVTVg==

Comment: Why do you need to decode the secret?

Comment: I read in the coinbase documentation that the secret must be decoded. This is a snippet from the [documentation](https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#signing-a-message).


"// decode the base64 secret
var key = Buffer(secret, 'base64');" 


I also see it in a lot of other example code in stackoverflow.

Comment: Did you fix it?? I am also confused by so many tutorial - each showing different approaces / libraries ... here is another example that I am trying https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/api-key-authentication

Comment: What language do you use ?? it looks like JavaScript but most of the other examples are Pyhton ..